# React: Accessing child component function but gives an undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, parent-child, state

So basically I'm trying to access a function in a child node (that returns the input of a text-box), from the parent node but i keep on getting an error stating that the function is not a function.

```
 MakeMethod.jsx:22 Uncaught TypeError: i.getState is not a function
        at MakeMethod.jsx:22
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at MakeMethod.getAllInfo (MakeMethod.jsx:22)
        at onClick (MakeMethod.jsx:41)
```

I've tried using the ref prop but it doesn't seem to work with an array of components.

The methods/function used to return the props parameter from the child node is the `getState()` one.
The method/function used to store the list of inputs from the children is the `getAllInfo()` one.

Is there something I'm doing drastically wrong? If so Would you be able to point it out to me?

Many thanks in advance!!

The parent class is the MakeMethod:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./MakeRecipe.css";
import Steps from "./Steps.jsx";
const count=1;
const theSteps=[]; //list of step components i want to access

class MakeMethod extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      count : 1,
    }
    this.AddMethod = this.AddMethod.bind(this);
    this.getAllInfo=this.getAllInfo.bind(this);
    theSteps.push(<Steps key={this.state.count} count={this.state.count} value={''}/>);
  }

  //this is the function i want to access all my information from
  getAllInfo(){
    let method=[];

    method=theSteps.map((i)=>
      i.getState() //iterates through each Step component and calls on the function getState()
                    //but it says that the function does not exist
      );
    this.setState({steps:method});
    console.log(method);
  }
    AddMethod(){
        let x=this.state.count+1;
        theSteps.push(<Steps key={x} count={x}/>);  
        this.setState({count:x}); 
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div key={"method"}>
         <div>
           {theSteps}
         </div>
         <button onClick={()=>this.AddMethod()}>Add another method?</button>
         <button onClick={()=>this.getAllInfo()}>checking info</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MakeMethod;
```

And the Child component is the Steps:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./MakeRecipe.css"
const count=1;

class Steps extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super();
      this.state = {value: ''};
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.getState = this.getState.bind(this);
    }

   //function that returns the value in the text box
    getState(){
      debugger;
      console.log(this.state.value); //tested and works
      return this.state.value; 
    }
   handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <div id={this.props.count}>
           <a>Step: {this.props.count}</a>
           <input key={this.props.count} type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
           <br/>
         </div>
         <button onClick={()=>this.getState()}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Steps;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't exactly know the React lifecycle and how does really works passage from Parent to Child and vice versa.

This is a pseudo code that puts you in the right direction

```
import React from 'react'; 
import Steps from "./Steps";
const count=1;
const theSteps=[]; //list of step components i want to access

class MakeMethod extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count : 1,
      theSteps:[] ,
      itemFromChild:''
    }
    this.AddMethod = this.AddMethod.bind(this);
    this.getAllInfo=this.getAllInfo.bind(this);
    this.state.theSteps.push(<Steps key={this.state.count} count={this.state.count} value={this.getAllInfo}/>);
  }

  //this is the function i want to access all my information from
      getAllInfo=(itemFromChild)=> {
        let method=[];
      this.setState({ itemFromChild });
       console.log(itemFromChild);
      } 
    getAllInfoLocal() {

       console.log(this.state.itemFromChild);
      } 
    AddMethod(){
        let x=this.state.count+1;
        theSteps.push(<Steps key={x} count={x}/>);  
        this.setState({count:x}); 
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div key={"method"}>
          {this.state.itemFromChild}
         <div>
           {this.state.theSteps}
         </div>
         <button onClick={()=>this.AddMethod()}>Add another method?</button>
         <button onClick={()=>this.getAllInfoLocal()}>checking info</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MakeMethod;
```

the other class...:

```
class Steps extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: ''};
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.getState = this.getState.bind(this);
    }

   //function that returns the value in the text box
    getState(){
      debugger;
      console.log(this.state.value); //tested and works
      return this.state.value; 
    }
   handleChange =  (event) =>{
       console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
     this.props.value(event.target.value);    
  }


  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <div id={this.props.count}>
           <a>Step: {this.props.count}</a>
           <input key={this.props.count} type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
           <br/>
         </div>
         <button onClick={()=>this.getState()}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Steps;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm i'm slightly confused with your pseudo. All that i want to do is access the information within the child components (Steps) through the parent component (MakeMethod). The 'theSteps' is just a list of child components in the parent component, and all i want to do is create an array of strings, that return the state of a given child (I know that sounds quite confusing). Is there any easy way of doing this?

Comment: you want to keep track of the state.value of the child inside a disting array for each Steps component?

Comment: Exactly that yes.

Comment: This is a different story. I think my answer helps you out in the main problem. If u need help again you need another question. Pls mask as answered if that helped you to figure out the problem on topic.

Comment: The button for each component was for debugging purposes. Just to see if it would return the right answer. this line here is redundant '<button onClick={()=>this.getState()}/>'

Answer (score 0):

Try to console log your component see what it will display.

Try i.getState. I think it should work since you're calling the property which is a function and not the callback of the function.

Also bind functions to the components like this:

```
getState = () => {
      debugger;
      console.log(this.state.value); //tested and works
      return this.state.value; 
}
```

since .bind has a lot of memory leaks.

Comment: Just tried the binding you recommended, and logged the array of child components. I tried to log it to the console but it just says that the elements in the array are undefined